# DVI - I Male to DVI - D Male Cable OR DVI - I to VGA Male Cable

Tags: dvi, vga, multiple-monitors

Alright. I have geforce 210 graphics card, It has one VGA port and one DVI - I Port.
I also got a DELL IN2020M 20" LED monitor which has VGA port and DVI - A Port.

Now, i already have a another monitor connected VGA (card) to VGA (monitor).
I want to add one more monitor to my setup.

How should i setup, so that i can get benefit of dual monitor?

Should i look for a DVI - I Male (for card) to VGA Male (for monitor) cable ? 
Or
Should i look for a DVI - I Male (for card) to DVI - D Male (for monitor) cable?
Also, can i use DVI - D male to DVI - D male cable for the setup i have. (remember, i have DVD-I on my gfx card)

Which one will be the best option for me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a DVI-D cable - A DVD-I port will accept a DVI-D cable.  DVD-I is the "universal" port, it caries both the digital and analog signal.

There is no reason you need to convert DVI to VGA.